# Find command fails to copy few files

Tags: find

I am using the command below to copy files created in the last minute. I scheduled the script which contains this command to run every one minute, so that the files can be copied as soon as the file is created in the a/b/c location. But, somehow this command fails to copy one or multiple files in sometimes. Is there any disadvantage in find command? or is there any error in following command?

```
find /a/b/c -type f -mmin -1 -exec cp {} /x/y/z \;
```

Comment: Are failed files successfuly copied at next iteration ?

Comment: No.I scheduled the script to run for every one minute.If it is not copied in one run, then it won't be copied.

Comment: find's mmin predicate looks at a file's "mtime"; have you seen whether the files that weren't copied had mtimes within the 1-minute window?

Comment: Then you're probably creating the files before running the script. Do the opposite and they should be copied.

Comment: How are you scheduling the script to run every minute?  Can you guarantee that it will run 60 seconds after the previous run, and not 61, no matter what else is happening on the machine?  Let's say your `find` command runs at 1:00 AM, and after it finishes, but within the same second, a file is created.  If the next run is 60 seconds later, it would find it, but if it was 61 seconds later, it wouldn't.  This seems like a flawed approach to the problem.

Comment: And for a more constructive answer: it sounds like what you're trying to do could be done instead with `rsync`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find` with a timestamp flag so that it picks up all files since the last run, regardless of how long ago that was. Feel free to replace the definition of `$trigger` with something more appropriate.

```
trigger=/tmp/trigger

touch "$trigger.new"
test ! -f "$trigger" && touch "$trigger"

find /a/b/c -newer "$trigger" -type f -exec cp -f {} /x/y/z +
mv -f "$trigger.new" "$trigger"
```

This will still fail in situations where the *mtime* is reset after the file has been completely written.

It will also still fail if the source file is being written when this code runs. It would be well worth protecting against this scenario unless you can guarantee that your source files appear atomically. One way of handling this is for your files to be written with a `.tmp` (or `.part`) suffix and renamed by the sender only when complete. The `find` in this trigger script here would be modified to exclude files whose names end with `.tmp` (or `.part`).

You could also use `rsync`, but be aware that directory paths in the source would be copied through to the destination, which may not be what you want. Replace the snippet above with this single line:

```
rsync -a /a/b/c/ /x/y/z/
```

Comment: Your solution with `find -newer $trigger` will still miss files modified between the `find` run and the subsequent `touch $trigger`. You need to update the trigger before running `find`. But rsync is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Gilles ah yes you're right. I wasn't thinking clearly enough. Will fix shortly

Comment: Thanks a lot for the brief explanation Roaima. The reason I didn't use rsynch is because it is not installed and can't be installed due to authorization restriction.                                                                               Could you please modify the code as Gillies suggested and explain the same step by steps? I couldn't under the code.

Comment: @M.Nehru if you can't use `rsync` use the first chunk of code I offered

Comment: @Roaima If you could modify the code as Gillies suggested and explain the steps of your code would be great. If I understand the code, I would be able use the code based on my requirements.

Comment: @M.Nehru the code was updated shortly after my comment on 21st June. You can see the changes by looking at the [edit history](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/210856/revisions)

Comment: @Roaima Could you please explain the code you have written.                               **mv: cannot stat `/tmp/trigger.new': No such file or directory**                                                                                                                                                                                            I  am getting this error sometimes. I could not fix it since, i didn't understand the process.

Comment: @M.Nehru that sounds like you're missing the initial `touch` command from the top of the code